# "Shutdown" or "Restart" logs out

Tags: 12.04, shutdown, restart, logout

While logged in as a `sudo` user, click the right top power icon, then select and click `Shutdown` menu, it comes up with a dialog asking if I want to close all programs. The dialog has two options: restart or shutdown. Choose either one logs me out. `Syslog` has the following line about restart:

> WARNING: Unable to restart system: Authorization is required

This happened after I installed NTP and some OpenStack packages while working in a prototype project. My Ubuntu's software is up to date as of this writing.

Anyone encountered the same problem in 12.04?

Comment: What is logged in as sudo user?

Comment: "While logged in as a sudo user" I mean the default user created by Ubuntu installation. This user can run commands like "sudo ....".

Comment: Same problem here under 12.04 (Lenovo thinkpad x121e). Can only use command line to restart/shut down the computer. Side effect is that my wife considers me a geek now as I shut down my laptop like this.

Comment: very bad bug, exists from 10.10 until now

Answer (score 8):

Sadly this is a known bug in (probably) `consolekit` [LP #838792](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/838792)

The workaround for the time is

```
sudo reboot

sudo shutdown now -P
```

Answer (score 3):

This should solve your problem: https://www.grendelman.net/wp/policykit-adventures/

Answer (score 1):

Following these websites information: http://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/0.105/pklocalauthority.8.html and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit/+bug/1033305

Seems to have resolved our problems with the lightdm shutdown button not working for all users on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.11.6-031106-generic x86_64)

```
vim /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/20-org.d/usershutdown.pkla
```

Then add the following lines to the file.

```
[Allow Shutdown]<br>
Identity=unix-user:\*;unix-group:*<br>
Action=org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.stop-multiple-users<br>
ResultAny=yes<br>
ResultInactive=yes<br>
ResultActive=yes<br>

[Allow Restart]<br>
Identity=unix-user:\*;unix-group:*<br>
Action=org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.restart-multiple-users<br>
ResultAny=yes<br>
ResultInactive=yes<br>
ResultActive=yes<br>
```

Then enter `service lightdm restart` and/or a reboot of the machine is needed. Tried before logging into the machine and then again after someone logged in.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this annoying little bug is this,
I create a launcher with the following:

To Shutdown:
`sudo shutdown -h`

To Restart:
`sudo shutdown -r`

You will then be asked your super user password.
I put this launcher on the desktop and use that 
until the bug is sorted out.

Comment: its not a little bug, its a big bug

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is caused by the HSQLDB Server. I just filled a bug about it:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hsqldb/+bug/1153856

Workaround:

```
sudo apt-get remove hsqldb-server
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same troubles - the guilty one was **kalarm**. After I disabled it, shutdown started to work properly again.

Comment: How do you disable this?

Answer (score 0):

A GUI resolution is to install [Cairo-dock](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cairo-dock&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all) from the repository and click on the Shutdown button on that menu to shutdown or restart.

While using the terminal commands work.  For some people, having to go to a terminal screen is at least, overly complicated, and also a lot of work.

I've been using this Gui workaround for the past 6 Ubuntu version releases.

This can be installed from the software center or cli:

```
$ sudo apt-get install cairo-dock
```