# Why does clicking 'Shutdown' from Menu only log me off?

Tags: 12.04, password, shutdown, password-recovery, accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Shutdown” or “Restart” logs out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122304/shutdown-or-restart-logs-out)

Whenever I click 'Shutdown' from the menu it just logs me off. I have no accounts (Exept from Guest, but I keep it logged off) logged on, but still, it just logs off and nothing else. I have Auto-Login on my only account, but I don't know the password and I'm trying to recover it.

Comment: password recovery is not possible but you can reset it from the live cd and from grub. Check: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Comment: I recommend [reporting this as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). Or find an existing bug report that applies, indicate you're affected with the green "This bug affects..." link near the top of the bug report, and if you have valuable additional information, post a comment on the bug. That guide explains how to search as well as how to file bug reports. ([This question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) also has some good information about bug reporting.)

Comment: @Eliah Kagan, but the person I got it off set it up for me. I don't know it and I've contacted the person who gave me it and he doesn't know. He might get round to it though.

Comment: @nerof61 You have the machine, so you can probably report the bug.

Comment: Ok, stop everything. I noticed that the admin had to be logged off, and I didn't know the password at the time. My friend contacted me yesterday and told me the password. Then the issue was gone like magic. Sorry for wasting your time everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an encrypted home directory?

I'm not sure of the exact issue... but I've observed this in a couple of machines with an encrypted home directory but not under other circumstances.

I **changed the encryption to Luks** and the issue disappeared like magic.

Comment: Sorry, as I am only a beginner, but whats a encrypted home directory?