# Ubuntu doesn't restart, but logs-out when restart button is pressed

Tags: reboot, restart, logout

The issues I am having with my Ubuntu is that when I am going for a restart, from the tray icon - Shutdown-->restart, it doesn't restart, but actually just logs out and gives me the ubuntu login screen again. I am having this issue since 3-4 days. Before that it wasn't happening. Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this post, addressing the same issue more alike:

["Shutdown" or "Restart" logs out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122304/shutdown-or-restart-logs-out)

Greets, 
Dafalgor.