# Shutdown just logging out

Tags: unity, shutdown, lightdm, 15.04, logout

I have an older hp pavilion all in one pc and after upgrading to 15.04 whenever I tell the computer to shutdown while in unity (haven't tried other DEs) it goes to the login screen as if I'd only pressed logout. It will then shutdown if I select shutdown from the menu in lightdm. But why is it doing this?

Comment: After attempting to do this does anything relevant appear in `/var/log/syslog` such as an error about unable to shutdown?

Comment: Related questions
https://askubuntu.com/questions/621732/shutdown-button-only-logs-out-ubuntu-15-04
https://askubuntu.com/questions/244239/why-does-clicking-shutdown-from-menu-only-log-me-off
https://askubuntu.com/questions/122304/shutdown-or-restart-logs-out
I'd flag as duplicate but I'm not familiar enough to know if this is the same situation, particular as that last one.

Comment: I think that purging and reinstalling `lightdm` might help you out.

Comment: I checked syslog in a terminal straight after it logged out and there is no error about not being able to shut down.

Comment: If `sudo shutdown -P now ` works make it a script or run manually till you resolve the issue.  Personally that's what I do 99% of the time. I'm guessing there's an issue with dbus since that's what unity uses, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Or better yet bind the command  to a keyboard shortcut. I'll find a link to another script I've used before and post if you're interested

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/554576/295286

Answer (score 2):

If you have docky installed this fixed the problem for both of my machines.

Ubuntu 15.04 Unity + Docky, Cairo-Dock, or Plank

(DOCKY)

```
cd ~/.config/autostart
nano docky.desktop
add X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=20
```

(IF YOU USE CAIRODOCK)

```
cd ~/.config/autostart
nano cairo-dock.desktop
add X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=20
```

Or you can remove either one from autostart.

Example docky.desktop in ~/.config/autostart with 20 second delay

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=docky
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=20
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=Docky
Name=Docky
Comment[en_US]=
Comment=
```